# Brother printer MFC-L2710DW not working

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I've connected my new printer, a Brother MFC-L2710DW, via wi-fi to my home network. It works smoothly on Windows, however I am encountering problems, on my Ubuntu 18.04 distribution. Whenever I try to print the Test Page or Self-Test Page, the job is sent to the printer and switch its state to `Processing` but nothing processed.

- I've added the printer both through the standard printer interface of 18.04 and the older one of the previous distributions.
- I've also downloaded the `Driver Install Tools` and run the
  installation but again, I've encountered the
  same problem.

Some thoughts on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have installed this multifunctional on Debian Stretch without any issues with the `Driver Install Tools` provided by Brother. It did not warn me that the script should be run as root, so you may want to try that out?
Also: if your system has AppArmor enabled, you may see error messages in the script output - the script does not cope well with errors, so you're left to yourself to read the script's output.

EDIT: I just found a page detailing so-called 'pre-required procedures': https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dw_us_eu_as&redirect=on#prereq

Instead of including these procedures in the installer script, Brother decided to document them on the website...

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad that link hasn't disappeared. I haven't unboxed mine, but I'm feeling optimistic now.